# Multiple Together Several Fields, then Use Update Cursor

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, fields-attributes, cursor

Is it possible to preform multiplication on several fields of an attribute table together and then use an update cursor to assign the resulting value to a specific field?

Comment: Uh, yes, but do you have any code that you can post in your question? What calculation is it you're trying to perform? Is it like A = B * C? A = B * Constant?..

Comment: Check the documentation here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000014000000. It would be along the lines of row[3] = row[0] * row[1] * row[2]

Comment: That's it @phloem, but make sure your data is numeric type. Bad things happen if the numbers are stored in a TEXT or DATE field. In these instances the values need to be cast to a number, multiplied and then stored.

Comment: While easy to do with a cursor, unless you want to learn some simple ArcPy, the field calculator will be even easier to use.

Comment: Yes, @MichaelMiles-Stimson, you are correct that results may differ based on data type, but that's really an answer to an unasked question.

Comment: Just a common pitfall @phloem, too often I've seen 'why isn't my code working' questions when there are no errors in the code, it's just that you can't multiply a string or concatenate an int and a string. Python doesn't have strong types and this sort of thing happens all too much... a lot of the time I do float(value), str(value) or int(value) just to be absolutely sure of the data type, not so with returned values from features, their types are strong - a text field will return string, even if the string is numeric.